# Strange, strange errors with vtables

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, inheritance, qt5

I'm moving my code from a previous API (SDL) to Qt 5.4. I have a few classes that are not related to Qt whatsoever, and have worked just fine on CodeBlocks/Visual studio. In my code here:

```
void ModelLoader::processNode(aiNode *node, const aiScene *scene, vector<Mesh> &mesh)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++)
    {
        aiMesh *me = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
        Mesh tmesh = processMesh(me, scene);
        mesh.push_back(tmesh); // Won't let me push back!
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
    {
        processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene, mesh);
    }
}
```

It would compile and run just fine on other IDES, but Qt Creator doesn't like it for some reason. The model loader class here doesn't inherit anything and whenever I compile with this code it gives me this error:

```
ModelLoader.o:-1: In function `QAbstractOpenGLFunctions::QAbstractOpenGLFunctions(QAbstractOpenGLFunctions const&)':

error: undefined reference to `vtable for QAbstractOpenGLFunctions'

:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is what's confusing: I am not inheriting at all from this class! But, I must admit that I can kinda see why it would say something like this. You see, the class 'Mesh' as well as other classes such as Texture etc: they all inherit from QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core, and they need to because they have to make use of OpenGL's functions. I don't want to create a pointer to the said class because that would make the code less readable. I initializeOpenGLFunctions() in the constructor of any class that inherits from it. I also implemented the virtual destructor in the Mesh class because I know from previous experience vtable errors usually derive similarly from such a reproach.

Since this code ran perfectly on another IDE, why would Qt Creator complain that with the said error above? Surely it does have something to do with QOpenGLFunctions. Ironically, all the classes that do inherit from the said class compile just fine; and if I omit ModelLoader then the code compiles and runs without any crashes whatsoever.

I've managed to isolated the problem to the function above; and from my findings the line of code that is causing the biggest problem is when I push back the temporary mesh that is the result of processMesh(..) which returns a Mesh. This code run fine under Codeblocks but it doesn't under Qt Creator. It's awfully frustrating because it's like Qt wants me to adopt a programming style that it wants, but I have no idea why this error is caused here and why it has something to do with this called called QAbstractOpenGL whatever. (Longest class name I've seen so far, really)

At first sight, it might have something to do with the Mesh class, because that inherits from QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core. If I comment out everything in Mesh's constructor (including the said class's initialization func) then I still get the same error.

I require the opinions of others, preferably from those who are familiar with Qt and the way it communicates with OpenGL with regards to this class. Why does this error occur on Qt Creator and not other IDEs? What is Qt asking for here?

Comment: Many compilers emit the `vtable` symbols together with the destructor (or the first virtual function if no destructor present or not virtual). So the _undefined vtable_ error happens when you fail to include in the project (link) the given corresponding `.cpp` file. Or if this file misses some member function. So check that you are comipling `ModelLoader.cpp` and that there is no unimplemented functions. And also the `Q_OBJECT` vodoo, of course.

Comment: What do you mean by the Q_OBJECT vodoo?

Comment: When you derive from `QObject` and you use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the declaration of the class, you have to use the `moc` to build the Qt magic that will turn your class into a Qt-class. If you fail to do that... well, you'll get weird linker errors...

Comment: On CodeBlocks/Visual Studio you was using Qt too? You can use any IDE with Qt, not just QtCreator, that's why i'm asking.

Comment: No, I'm only using Qt with Qt Creator. I'm not experienced with Qt, but I do understand that anything Q* inherits from QObject. Not that I want to break the Q continuoum but I try to keep my C++ code separate from Qt in terms of classes; but it probably requires deliberation as a result of inheriting from the QOpenGLFunction class. I didn't use the macro Q_OBJECT on any of the classes that inherit from it; and yet they could compile.

Comment: Such `undefined reference to vtable` errors usually mean one thing: that you declared some virtual methods that you did not implement. `Q_OBJECT` notably does this: declares some virtual methods that `moc` implements (thus `moc` not running => error). Can you paste the definition of your class?

Comment: Which class? ModelLoader inherits nothing; but Mesh does, but it doesn't initialise the OpenGL context; it simply uses OpenGL functions.

Comment: Which class is holding a pointer to a `QOpenGLFunctions` thing of some sort? That class is being copied around.

Comment: There is no class that is holding a pointer to QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core. A class that uses 4.3 GL functions inherits from the class and is used within other classes that might or might not inherit QOpenGLFunctions.

Comment: I think I solved the error I got. What I did in the Mesh class was create a static pointer to QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core and called OpenGL functions through that pointer. I ceased the inheritance Mesh had. I just want reassurance in this regard: is this how I should be using QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core? I shouldn't be inheriting from it at all lest vtable errors come up?

Comment: The problem is that you were copying Mesh, thus also asking its QOpenGLFunctions base to copy. But that class can't be copied. Use a member (instead of inheriting) if you plan to copy. Or reorganize your code (i.e. split the "mesh data", i.e. the raw buffers and attributes etc., from the logic that manages those mesh data)